# Contours from delaunay triangles

Tags: contour, tin, delaunay

I have generated a delaunay polygon file that represents terrain data. Is there a way I can produce contours from the polygon file? I know I can convert the polygon to an Esri TIN, and then produce other products, but is there a way to do it directly from the polygon?

Comment: Where in the polygons is the elevation represented, that is, is it in the nodes of the corners, or the center?

Comment: Both...it is a ZM polygon with nodes having elevation, and the record has an elevation value in the attribute table

Comment: There is this in R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contoureR/index.html

Comment: @RyanGarnett if those polygons were converted to points first, would the elevation values be preserved?